# Products in cart removed when user logs out

Tags: checkout, cart, customer, login

When a customer is logged in, he got some products in the cart and he logs out. 
The products are removed from the cart and the cart is completely empty.

How can I fix that when a customer logs out, the products stay in the cart?

I do use the persistent shopping cart

Answer (score 2):

In the checkout module there is an observer for the event `customer_logout`.

```
        <customer_logout>
            <observers>
                <unsetAll>
                    <class>checkout/observer</class>
                    <method>unsetAll</method>
                </unsetAll>
            </observers>
        </customer_logout>
```

This means that the method `Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer::unsetAll` is called when the user logs out.
You can try to remove this observer or rewrite the method and make it do nothing. But I'm not 100% sure of the implications.